# Does passing an instance of a parcelable object via intent leak memory?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-intent, parcelable

I have a number of classes that implement the `Parcelable` interface so that I can pass instances of those objects between activities. I'm trying to understand how this does/does not cause a memory leak.

If an object is create in one activity and passed via `Intent` to another, I would guess this would pass a reference to that object. Based on my (potentially wrong) understanding of how the garbage collector works, this would create a reference from the receiving activity to the sending activity and create a memory leak as the sending activity could not be garbage collected in that state.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html. May be this will help you understand better

Comment: My guess is that the Intent is handled at the application level, not the activity level. So of course, when you leave the first activity, it can be garbage-collected. It is not the activities themselves that handle the navigation in the app, but other objects higher in the hierarchy; those are the ones that handle the intents.

Comment: @personne3000 I'll look into that as a possibility. It makes sense if that's how the intents are handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an object is create in one activity and passed via Intent to another, I would guess this would pass a reference to that object.

AFAIK, no, because activity creation goes by way of a core OS process. I would expect a copy to be made as a result of this, with a side effect of not having the GC issue you outlined.

Comment: Why because they are not static? Maybe I'm just missing when you'd pass a references vs. a copy.

Comment: @Rarw: You cannot pass by reference across OS process boundaries.

Comment: Ah so between activities it will always pass a copy